# close popup window from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Java script function tom open popup window from extension

```
var trackchildwindow;

$('#done').submit(function(){
    trackchildwindow=chrome.windows.create({url: 'chrome-extension://'+<extensionid>+'/src/browser_action/ChildPage.html', type: 'popup' , focused: true, 'width': 900 ,'height': 700, 'left': 600, 'top': 800 });
```

});

In the same javascript file function to close the popup window

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {             
        Chrome.windows.remove(trackchildwindow.id, function(){});  
    };
```

However it fails to close the popup window. I have tried using `trackchildwindow.close();` too. Not working . Any help will be appreciated 
............................edited ....................

I have found my answer

```
Buttonclose= function close(){
    open(location, '_self').close();
}
```

That is it . For record keeping from my main window I am using

chrome.extension.sendMessage

Comment: Please post an answer _as an answer_, instead of adding it to the question. You can even accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trackchildwindow = chrome.windows.create(options);
```

is not working, because the function is asynchronous and does not return anything (as does most of the Chrome API)

You need to deal with it [in a callback](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create):

```
chrome.windows.create(options, function(win) {
  trackchildwindow = win;
  // Note, this is asynchronous..
});
// ..and as such trackchildwindow is not defined here yet
```

Since the code is asynchronous, you need to be careful when you use the value.

Comment: hey Xan , Problem doesnot lie in opening the popup window , but closing it . I want to close the popup child window from parent window where it was created

Comment: In your code, `trackchildwindow == undefined`, so no wonder you can't close it. Are you debugging this? Do you see any errors?

Comment: no errors . As per your suggestion i added a callback function so now code becomes.                                                    chrome.windows.create({url: 'chrome-extension://'+<extsnszionid>+'/src/browser_action/ChildPage.html', type: 'popup' , focused: true, 'width': 900 ,'height': 700, 'left': 600, 'top': 800 },function(win) {
      trackchildwindow = win;
      console.log(" tracking --> "+trackchildwindow);
    }); . However it is still undefined

Comment: after adding the call back function the popup window doesnt open at all . no errors on console .